# How to join 100 random rows from table 1 multiple other tables in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have scrapped my previous question as I did not do a good job explaining. Maybe this will be simpler.

I have the following query.

```
Select * from comp_eval_hdr, comp_eval_pi_xref, core_pi, comp_eval_dtl
where comp_eval_hdr.START_DATE between TO_DATE('01-JAN-16' , 'DD-MON-YY') 
and TO_DATE('12-DEC-17' , 'DD-MON-YY')
and comp_eval_hdr.COMP_EVAL_ID = comp_eval_dtl.COMP_EVAL_ID
and comp_eval_hdr.COMP_EVAL_ID = comp_eval_pi_xref.COMP_EVAL_ID
and core_pi.PI_ID = comp_eval_pi_xref.PI_ID
and core_pi.PROGRAM_CODE = 'PS'
```

Now if I only want a random 100 rows from the comp_eval_hdr table to join with the other tables how would I go about it? If it makes it easier you can disregard the comp_eval_dtl table.

Comment: Struggling with what? What do the other tables look like?

Comment: I edited to potentially simplify. Let's just say 2 table. Table a has records and table b has details for those records.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are pretty much there.  You just need subqueries, table aliases, and `JOIN` conditions:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM (SELECT a.*
      FROM (SELECT a.*
            FROM a
            WHERE a.START_DATE BEWTWEEN DATE '2016-01-01' AND DATE '2017-12-12' 
            ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE
           ) a
      WHERE ROWNUM <= 100
     ) a JOIN
     mapping m
     ON a.? = m.? JOIN
     b
     ON m.? = b.?;
```

The `?` is just a placeholder for the join columns.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a stretch to know what you want with the question as written but here's my attempt.

```
WITH rand_list AS
   (SELECT * FROM comp_eval_hdr
    WHERE  comp_eval_hdr.START_DATE BEWTWEEN TO_DATE('01-JAN-16' , 'DD-MON-YY') AND TO_DATE('12-DEC-17' , 'DD-MON-YY') 
    ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE)
     first_100 AS
    (SELECT *
     FROM   rand_list    
     WHERE ROWNUM <=100)
SELECT md.col_1, t3.col_a
  FROM first_100 md     
       INNER JOIN
       table2 t2 ON md.id_column = t2.fk_comp_eval_hdr_id
       INNER JOIN
       table3 t3 ON t3.id_column = t2.fk_table3_id
```

You haven't given any indication how they join or the table names and obviously I haven't run this against any mock tables.
You've got a list of randomised records with RAND_LIST which you could, if you wanted, combine with the FIRST_100 query (your choice).
The main query then just joins that through your mapping table (T2) to your 'multiples' table (T3).

Answer (score 0):

how does table 2 look like?...Let me put one example as person table and order table?

select * from (
select * from person ps , order order where ps.city = 'mumbai' and ps.id = order.purchasedby ) porder where porder.rownum <= 100

I did not tested it but it will look something like this.

Comment: edited my question if it makes it easier to understand